# Deleting contents from geodatabase in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, delete

I have a geodatabase and I would like to be able to delete layers in there easily using ArcPy. Also select which type of files.

**Example: delete all file *tables* from the gdb or all *layers*.**

Code:

```
env.workspace = r"path.gdb"
for i in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
    #how to delete?
```

Comment: Just something to consider, if you wanted to purge a geodatabase completly (i.e. remove all it's contents) it will be quicker to delete the geodatabase itself and create another. You would do that if you don't care about any domains or metadata.

Comment: Be aware that geodatabases do not contain layers but they can contain feature classes that layers in a map or layer-file are using as their source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
env.workspace = r"path.gdb"
fc_list = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
tables = arcpy.ListTables()
ds_list = arcpy.ListDatasets()

#feature classes
for fc in fc_list:
    arcpy.Delete_management(fc)

#tables
for table in tables:
    arcpy.Delete_management(table)

#data sets
for ds in ds_list:
    arcpy.Delete_management(ds)
```

There are many options to modify each of list so head to help links to get more info.

**Help links:**

**feature clases** - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listfeatureclasses.htm

**tables** - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listtables.htm

**data sets**  - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/listdatasets.htm

**delete** - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete.htm